# Starcraft 2: Is there a way to auto assign units to a ctrl group?

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In StarCraft 2, is there a way to automatically set groups on units about to be produced?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4890/in-starcraft-2-is-there-a-way-to-automatically-set-groups-on-units-about-to-be-p)

When I'm battling in SC2, I often set my Barracks rally point to to a unit I try to keep safe so when a new Marine is created it will move over to where my view is..

I'd actually like to be able to set the Marine, Firebat, Vulture, whatever unit to be auto assigned to a control group on creation, so that I can just hit 1 and attack instead of waiting for that unit to appear in my view then add it to the group.

Is this possible? Or am I asking for the impossible? :D

Thanks.